# "More than one operator "!=" matches these operands" error not stopping compilation?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

So I have a template class `TargetVar` which is essentially just a wrapper for another variable such that I can set a target value for said variable and how many frames it should take to reach that value. Every frame, I call a process function on each `TargetVar` which moves its value towards the target value.

Here's the class:

```
class BaseTargetVar {
public:
    BaseTargetVar() {
        TargetVarManager::get_instance()->register_target_var(this); //TargetVarManager just iterates 
        //through all registered TargetVars and calls their process funcs
    }
    virtual ~BaseTargetVar() {
        TargetVarManager::get_instance()->unregister_target_var(this);
    }

    virtual void process() {}
};

template <class T> class TargetVar : public BaseTargetVar {
public:
    TargetVar() = default;


    TargetVar(T& other) {
        if (val != other) {
            val = other;
            frames = 0;
        }
    }
    
    TargetVar(const T& other) {
        if (val != other) {
            val = other;
            frames = 0;
        }
    }

    void process() override {
        if (frames) {
            val += target_change_per_frame;
            frames--;
            if (!frames) {
                val = target_val;
            }
        }
    }
    
    void set_target_val(T target_val, unsigned int frames) {
        if (target_val == this->target_val) return;
        this->target_val = target_val;
        target_change_per_frame = target_val - val;
        target_change_per_frame /= frames;
        this->frames = frames;
    }

    void set_val(const T& val) {
        this->val = val;
    }

    T get_val() const {
        return val;
    }

    T* get_val_addr() const {
        return &val;
    }

    T get_target_change_per_frame() const {
        return target_change_per_frame;
    }

    unsigned int get_frames() const {
        return frames;
    }
private:
    T val{};
    T target_val{};
    T target_change_per_frame{};
    unsigned int frames = 0;
};
```

One of the main uses for this class in my project is to use a `TargetVar<glm::vec3>` in order to handle the position of a texture. Because of this, it's common to compare a `TargetVar<T>` to a `T` (E.G. comparing the position of a texture to a position on the screen, I.E. `TargetVar<glm::vec3>` to `glm::vec3`), but it's also common to compare a `TargetVar<T>` to another `TargetVar<T>` (E.G. comparing the position of a texture to the position of another texture, I.E. `TargetVar<glm::vec3>` to `TargetVar<glm::vec3>`). In order to make this more convenient, I added the following operator overloads to the `TargetVar` class:

```
    template <typename U>
    TargetVar<T>& operator=(const U& rhs) {
        val = (T)rhs;
        frames = 0;
        return *this;
    }

    template <typename U>
    bool operator==(const U& rhs) {
        return val == rhs;
    }

    template <typename U>
    bool operator!=(const U& rhs) {
        return val != rhs;
    }

    template <typename U>
    TargetVar<T>& operator=(const TargetVar<U>& rhs) {
        if (this != &rhs) {
            val = rhs.get_val();
            frames = 0;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    template <typename U>
    bool operator==(const TargetVar<U>& rhs) {
        return val == rhs.get_val();
    }

    template <typename U>
    bool operator!=(const TargetVar<U>& rhs) {
        return val != rhs.get_val();
    }
```

This system has worked for a few weeks without any issues, but I've noticed that certain comparisons cause an error in VS. For example:

```
    TargetVar<glm::vec3> tv1 = glm::vec3(0.0);
    TargetVar<glm::vec3> tv2 = glm::vec3(0.0);
    if (tv1 != tv2) {
        /*
            Error E0350 - more than one operator "!=" matches these operands:
            function template "bool TargetVar<T>::operator==(const U &rhs) [with T=glm::vec3]", with reversed arguments
            function template "bool TargetVar<T>::operator==(const TargetVar<U> &rhs) [with T=glm::vec3]", with reversed arguments
            function template "bool TargetVar<T>::operator!=(const U &rhs) [with T=glm::vec3]"
            function template "bool TargetVar<T>::operator!=(const TargetVar<U> &rhs) [with T=glm::vec3]"
            operand types are: TargetVar<glm::vec3> != TargetVar<glm::vec3>
        */
    }
    if (tv1 == tv2) {
        /*
            Error E0350 - more than one operator "==" matches these operands:
            function template "bool TargetVar<T>::operator==(const U &rhs) [with T=glm::vec3]", with reversed arguments
            function template "bool TargetVar<T>::operator==(const TargetVar<U> &rhs) [with T=glm::vec3]", with reversed arguments
            function template "bool TargetVar<T>::operator==(const U &rhs) [with T=glm::vec3]"
            function template "bool TargetVar<T>::operator==(const TargetVar<U> &rhs) [with T=glm::vec3]"
            operand types are: TargetVar<glm::vec3> == TargetVar<glm::vec3>

        */
    }
    if (tv1 != tv2.get_val()) {
        //No errors
    }
    if (tv1 == tv2.get_val()) {
        //No errors
    }
    if (tv1.get_val() != tv2.get_val()) {
        //No errors
    }
    if (tv1.get_val() == tv2.get_val()) {
        //No errors
    }
```

These errors don't actually stop the program from compiling, but I'm wondering why VS thinks there's an issue with the tv1 to tv2 comparison but not the tv1 to tv2.get_val() comparison.

Also, out of curiosity I removed the != operator overloads to see if the "with reversed arguments" bit would go away. It didn't change anything about the existing errors, but it did introduce the following errors which DID cause the program not to compile:

```
if (tv1 != tv2) {
    /*
        Error C2666 - 'TargetVar<glm::vec3>::operator ==': overloaded functions have similar conversions
    */
}
if (tv1 == tv2) {
    /*
        Error C2666 - 'TargetVar<glm::vec3>::operator ==': overloaded functions have similar conversions
    */
}
```

At the end of the day the program works just fine as-is, but I'm wondering why VS only has a problem with that specific case and if there's anything I can do about it other than manually putting .get_val() in all of my operations.

Comment: This is probably not related to your problem, but when comparison operators are implemented as member functions, they should be marked `const`. For example: `template <typename U> bool operator==(const U& rhs) const { ... }`. Otherwise you will have trouble using them to compare non-constant objects.

Answer (score 3):

So.... `Cxxxx` series errors come from the actual compiler when you run a build.  `Exxxx` errors are from the editor.  The editor's interpretation of C++ code is a bit wonky at times, because it makes an effort to figure out code that's invalid because it's in the middle of being edited.  Bodies of class members that no longer match the declaration in the class itself, things like that.

When the editor gets it wrong, it will affect actions like "GoTo Definition", but won't stop you from building.

The editor gets it wrong often enough that I usually turn off error/warning messages from the editor, from the dropdown on top of the Error List.

[image]

Actually, I hardly even use the Error List window, preferring the "Build" tab of the Output window, where the full error messages can be seen without being forced into the neat n-column table.